# How can i remove an element in Deployment volumeMounts with kubectl Patch command?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Deployment like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /home
        name: john-webos-vol
        subPath: home
      - mountPath: /pkg
        name: john-vol
        readOnly: true
        subPath: school
```

I want to change the Deloyment with the `kubectl patch` command, so it has the following `volumeMounts` in the `PodTemplate` instead:

**target.yaml:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /home
        name: john-webos-vol
        subPath: home
```

I used the below command, but it didn't work.

```sh
kubectl patch deployment sample --patch "$(cat target.yaml)"
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: is this one is your final yaml? i mean you didn't provide the container spec or ather ones

Comment: make sure you provide enough info so that we can regenerate your problems

Comment: This is not even a valid yaml file. Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSON patch http://jsonpatch.com/

##### Remove specific volume mount

```
kubectl patch deployment <NAME> --type json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts/0"}]'
```

##### Replace volume mounts with what you need

```
kubectl patch deployment <NAME> --type json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts", "value": [{"mountPath": "/home", "name": "john-webos-vol", "subPath": "home"}]}]'
```

Kubectl cheet sheet for more info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#patching-resources

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this with `kubectl patch`. The patch you did in your problem is called a `strategic merge patch`. the patch can't replace things,  instead with this patch you can only add things.

like if you have intially one `container` in your `podspec` but you need to add another `container`. you can use `patch` here to add another `container`. but if you have two `container` and need to remove one you can't do this with this kind of patch.

if you want to this with `patch` you need to use `retainKeys`. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment-using-the-retainkeys-strategy)

let me explain how you can do this in another simple way. lets assume you have applied below test.yaml with
`kubectl apply  -f  test.yaml`

**test.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home
          name: john-webos-vol
          subPath: home
        - mountPath: /pkg
          name: john-vol
          readOnly: true
          subPath: school
      volumes:
      - name: john-webos-vol
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: john-vol
        emptyDir: {}
```

now you need update this one. and the updated one **target.yaml** will remove one of volume .

**target.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /pkg
          name: john-vol
          readOnly: true
          subPath: school
      volumes:
      - name: john-vol
        emptyDir: {}
```

you can just use:

```
 kubectl apply -f target.yaml
```

this one will update your deployment with new configuration

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that you need to have the initial spec at your hands to overwrite the old one. It's not even technically updating anything -- it's just an overwrite. So, if you need to update a whole batch of deployments, you need to get the original `yaml`, before adding something, then add something, then overwrite the modified spec with the original `yaml`. It's a bad way of handling this scenario and if this is truly the only way at this moment, I hope the Kubernetes team will be able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the **apply** command, by getting the deployment definition in JSON format, modifying (in your case removing) this section

```
  - mountPath: /pkg
    name: john-vol
    readOnly: true
    subPath: school
```

with sed or a simmilar utility and then applying it back:

```
kubectl get deployment <myDeployment> -n <myNamespace> | sed -z -s -E -b -e 's/REGEX_TO_MATCH_PART_OF_DEPLOYMENT_TO_REMOVE//g' | kubectl apply -f -
```